# Brackets Git error message

Tags: git, brackets

I am getting this error message when trying to use brackets to clone my repo from GitHub:  Brackets Git encountered an error...  Expected error: Project root is not empty, be sure have deleted hidden files. I am new this whole thing, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I have a Windows 10 PC. I am not sure what brackets is talking about? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I have a sense of dupe.

Comment: tried this ? - https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-git/issues/1061